# ANTD React How can I do affix like antd website?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to affix the buttons in the bottom right corner as on the antd website. I couldn't do this

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried to achieve this?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, because i dont know how can i do this, I want a button that is fixed in the bottom right corner of the screen that moves with the scrollbar this example I want is used as the theme change button on the antd website.. @Agney

Comment: sadly that is not how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve this. Before that, I would recommend you to show us what you have tried. Stackoverflow should be used when you aren't able to achieve what you desire. Please don't repeat the same in the near future. BTW, you can do this by using `Affix` as you told. This should have a `Button` which has an icon. This will keep the icon fixed at the right bottom of page.

```
import {Button, Affix} from 'antd';
import { wechat } from '@ant-design/icons'

<Affix style={{position:'fixed',bottom:10,right:10}}>
  <Button type="primary" icon="wechat" />
</Affix>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, actually, the solution is really simple, but I couldn't come up with an idea of ​​how I could do it when I didn't see it in the documentation. Thx

Comment: Yeah., Documentation has everything clear and precise. Do follow those, spend just a couple of hours skimming through the documentation and this will make you quickly get whatever you want in the future. **Happy Coding!!**